# tensorflow: difference between multi GPUs and distributed tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am little confused about these two concepts.

I saw some examples about multi GPU without using clusters and servers in the code.

Are these two different? What is the difference?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It depends a little on the perspective from which you look at it.  In any multi-* setup, either multi-GPU or multi-machine, you need to decide how to split up your computation across the parallel resources.  In a single-node, multi-GPU setup, there are two very reasonable choices:

(1)  **Intra-model parallelism**.  If a model has long, independent computation paths, then you can split the model across multiple GPUs and have each compute a part of it.  This requires careful understanding of the model and the computational dependencies.

(2)  **Replicated training**.  Start up multiple copies of the model, train them, and then synchronize their learning (the gradients applied to their weights & biases).

Our [released Inception model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) has some good diagrams in the readme that show how both multi-GPU and distributed training work.

But to tl;dr that source:  In a multi-GPU setup, it's often best to synchronously update the model by storing the weights on the CPU (well, in its attached DRAM).  But in a multi-machine setup, we often use a separate "parameter server" that stores and propagates the weight updates.  To scale that to a lot of replicas, you can shard the parameters across multiple parameter servers.

With multiple GPUs and parameter servers, you'll find yourself being more careful about device placement using constructs such as `with tf.device('/gpu:1')`, or placing weights on the parameter servers using [`tf.train.replica_device_setter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#replica_device_setter) to assign it on `/job:ps` or `/job:worker`.

In general, training on a bunch of GPUs in a single machine is much more efficient -- it takes more than 16 distributed GPUs to equal the performance of 8 GPUs in a single machine -- but distributed training lets you scale to even larger numbers, and harness more CPU.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: The inception link is broken. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/16e4679834e1bf3e805703b197d377e35504fa09/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) is another example.

Answer (score 0):

Well until recently there was no open-source cluster version of tensor flow - just single machine with zero or more GPU.
The new release v0.9 may or may not have changed things.
The article in the original release documentation (Oct 2015) showed that Google has cluster-based solutions - but they had not open-sourced them.

Here is what the [whitepaper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) says:

> 3.2 Multi-Device Execution Once a system has multiple devices, there are two main complications: deciding which device to place the computation for each node in the graph, and then managing the required
>   communication of data across device boundaries implied by these
>   placement decisions. This subsection discusses these two issues

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, they announced that they released distributed tensorflow with their v0.8, and they have an tutorial page for that: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/distributed/index.html. Is that not the real distributed tensorflow?

Comment: this is great news! - let's hope someone steps in who is "up to steam" on this.