# Distributed tensorflow replicated training example: grpc_tensorflow_server - No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, distributed-computing, grpc

I am trying to make a `distributed tensorflow` implementation by following the instructions in this blog: [Distributed TensorFlow by Leo K. Tam](http://leotam.github.io/general/2016/03/13/DistributedTF.html). My aim is to perform `replicated training` as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37733117/5082406)

I have completed the steps till `installing tensorflow` and successfully running the following command and getting results:

```
sudo bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu
```

Now the next thing, which I want to implement is to launch the `gRPC server` on one of the nodes by the following command :

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_tensorflow_server --cluster_spec='worker|192.168.555.254:2500;192.168.555.255:2501' --job_name=worker --task_id=0 &
```

Though, when I run it, I get the following error: `rpc/grpc_tensorflow_server:No such file directory`

```
-bash: bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_tensorflow_server: No such file or directory
```

The contents of my `rpc` folder are:

```
 libgrpc_channel.pic.a              libgrpc_remote_master.pic.lo       libgrpc_session.pic.lo             libgrpc_worker_service_impl.pic.a  _objs/                             
 libgrpc_master_service_impl.pic.a  libgrpc_remote_worker.pic.a        libgrpc_tensor_coding.pic.a        libgrpc_worker_service.pic.a       
 libgrpc_master_service.pic.lo      libgrpc_server_lib.pic.lo          libgrpc_worker_cache.pic.a         librpc_rendezvous_mgr.pic.a
```

I am clearly missing out on a step in between, which is not mentioned in the blog. My objective is to be able to run the command mentioned above (to launch the `gRPC server`) so that I can start a worker process on one of the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grpc_tensorflow_server` binary was a temporary measure used in the pre-released version of Distributed TensorFlow, and it is no longer built by default or included in the binary distributions. Its replacement is the [`tf.train.Server`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Server) Python class, which is more programmable and easier to use.

You can write simple Python scripts using `tf.train.Server` to reproduce the behavior of `grpc_tensorflow_server`:

```
# ps.py. Run this on 192.168.0.1. (IP addresses changed to be valid.)
import tensorflow as tf
server = tf.train.Server({"ps": ["192.168.0.1:2222"]},
                         {"worker": ["192.168.0.2:2222", "192.168.0.3:2222"]},
                         job_name="ps", task_index=0)
server.join()

# worker_0.py. Run this on 192.168.0.2.
import tensorflow as tf
server = tf.train.Server({"ps": ["192.168.0.1:2222"]},
                         {"worker": ["192.168.0.2:2222", "192.168.0.3:2222"]},
                         job_name="worker", task_index=0)
server.join()

# worker_1.py. Run this on 192.168.0.3. (IP addresses changed to be valid.)
import tensorflow as tf
server = tf.train.Server({"ps": ["192.168.0.1:2222"]},
                         {"worker": ["192.168.0.2:2222", "192.168.0.3:2222"]},
                         job_name="worker", task_index=1)
server.join()
```

Clearly this example could be cleaned up and made reusable with command-line flags etc., but TensorFlow doesn't prescribe a particular form for these. The main things to note is that (i) there is one `tf.train.Server` instance per TensorFlow task, (ii) all `Server` instances must be constructed with the same "cluster definition" (the dictionary mapping job names to lists of addressess), and (iii) each task is identified by a unique pair of `job_name` and `task_index`.

Once you run the three scripts on the respective machines,,  you can create another script to connect to them:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session("grpc://192.168.0.2:2222")
# ...
```

Comment: It gave me an error : TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'task_id'
So i went through the documents and changed `task_id` to `task_index` and it works

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I updated the example with the correction.

Comment: Also if I start the ps server, say on 192.168.254.250 with the same port 2500 it does not work. BTW can you please post an example where I have one ps server and two worker servers. It'll be of great help.

Comment: Correct: you can only run one server (and hence one unique TensorFlow task) on a single port. I'll add a PS to the example.

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely helpful for a beginner like me. :)