# Image processing in TensorFlow distributed session

Tags: opencv, session, tensorflow, distributed, preprocessor

I am testing out the Tensorflow Distributed (https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) with my local machine (Windows) and Ubuntu VM. Where, 
I have followed this link [Distributed tensorflow replicated training example: grpc_tensorflow_server - No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027488/distributed-tensorflow-replicated-training-example-grpc-tensorflow-server-no) and set up the Tensorflow so called server like as per below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
parameter_servers = ["10.0.3.15:2222"]
workers = ["10.0.3.15:2222","10.0.3.15:2223"]
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": parameter_servers, "worker": workers})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="local", task_index=0)
server.join()
```

Where   “10.0.3.15” – is my Ubuntu local ip address. 
In the windows host machine – I am doing some simple image preprocessing using open cv and extending the graph session to the VM. I have used following code for that.

```
  *import tensorflow as tf
  from OpenCVTest import *
  with tf.Session("grpc:// 10.0.3.15:2222") as sess:
  ### Open CV calling section ###
  img = cv2.imread('Data/ball.jpg')
  grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
  flat_img_array = img.flatten()
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(flat_img_array[0],flat_img_array[1]))
  y = tf.multiply(x, x)
  sess.run(y)*
```

I can see that my session is running on my Ubunu machine. Please see below screenshot.

[Test_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVKS9.png)

[ Note- In the image you would notice, in Windows console I am calling the session and Ubuntu terminal is listening to that same session. ]

But strange thing I have observed is that for the OpenCV preprocessing operation (grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)) it’s leveraging local OpenCV package. I was in assumption that when I am running a session on any other server it should do all the operation on that server. In my case as I am running the session on Ubuntu VM, it should run all the operation which has been defined with tf.Session("grpc:// 10.0.3.15:2222") in this should also be running on that ubuntu VM leveraging VM’s local packages, but that’s not happening. 
Is my understanding of the  sess.run(y) distributed correct ? When we run the session in a distributed manner. Does it only extend the graph computation load to another machine through gRPC ? 
I would summarize my ask like this -  “I am planning to do large pre-preprocessing before feeding the value to the tensor and I want to do it in a distributed way. What would be the better approach to follow ? My initial understanding was I can with tensorflow distributed but with this test I think I may not able to do it.“
Any thoughts would be of real help.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sumit, Did you get any solution for the above problem??